# Logging with EntLib Policy Injection Block + StructureMap + log4net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enterprise-library, aop, structuremap

I'm trying to add **logging through AOP in an ASP.NET MVC** application using:

- Enterprise Library Policy Injection application Block
- StructureMap
- log4net

This is what I have:

web.config

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="policyInjection" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.Configuration.PolicyInjectionSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>   

  <policyInjection>
    <policies>
      <add name="Policy">
        <matchingRules>
          <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.MatchingRules.TagAttributeMatchingRule, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
            match="Log" name="Tag Attribute Matching Rule" />
        </matchingRules>
        <handlers>
          <add type="MyApp.Website.MyLoggingCallHandler, MyApp.Website, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
            name="Custom Handler" />
        </handlers>
      </add>
    </policies>
  </policyInjection>
```

Bootstrapper:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new StructureMapControllerFactory());
```

StructureMapControllerFactory:

```
public class StructureMapControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
  protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
  {
    var instance = ObjectFactory.GetInstance(controllerType);
    return PolicyInjection.Wrap<IController>(instance);
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Tag("Log")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  //Implementation
}
```

MyLoggingCallHandler:

```
namespace MyApp.Website
{
    [ConfigurationElementType(typeof(CustomCallHandlerData))]
    public class MyLoggingCallHandler : ICallHandler
    {
        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
        {
          //Implementation
        }

        public int Order { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The issue is: the **call handler is never fired**.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here:
http://entlib.codeplex.com/discussions/352050